# Google Autocomplete api and map API throwing error in console not loading either

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, callback

Im trying to get my Google map API to work, i have an auto complete callback and a map callback but when i try to launch through chrome it throws this error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. Its showing the API callback function as the error but i cant figure out why im pretty sure the callback is correct.

```js
<script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<mykey>=initMap&libraries=places'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue simple syntax error at start of API link